# undefined index en POST en cualquiera de los 2 modales

Tags: php, html

Tengo un problema al enviar un post de cualquiera de los 2 forms. Siempre salta el seguiente notice

```
 Notice: Undefined index: nombre in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: apellido in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: sexo in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: nacimiento in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 21
```

Como hago para que no aparezca? Ya que luego de actualizar la pagina puede loguearse perfectamente el usuario.

Este es `validar.php`

```
public static function validarUsuario($miUsuario){
    $errores = [];

    if(trim($miUsuario["nombre"]) == ""){
      $errores[] = "Falta el nombre";
    }

    if(trim($miUsuario["apellido"]) == ''){
      $errores[] = "Falta el apellido";
    }

    if(trim($miUsuario["mail"])== ""){
      $errores[] = "Falta el mail";
    }

    if(trim($miUsuario["pass"]) == ""){
      $errores[]= "Falta el password";
    }

    if(trim($miUsuario["cpass"]) == ""){
      $errores[] = "Confirma el password";
    }

    if(!isset($miUsuario["sexo"])){
      $errores[] = "Selecciona un sexo";
    }

    if(!date($miUsuario["nacimiento"])){
      $errores[] = "Escribi bien la fecha";
    }

    if($miUsuario["pass"] !== $miUsuario["cpass"]){
      $errores[] = "Las contraseñas no coinciden";
    }

    if(!filter_var($miUsuario["mail"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
      $errores[] = "Formato email incorrecto";
    }
    return $errores;
  }

   function validarLogin(){
      $errores = [];
      if (trim($_POST["mail"]) == "") {
          $errores[] = "No pusiste email";
      } else if (!$this->userRepository->existeElMail($_POST["mail"])) {
          $errores[] = "El mail no existe";
      } else if (!$this->userRepository->usuarioValido($_POST["mail"], $_POST["pass"])) {
          $errores [] = "El usuario no es valido";
      }
      if (trim($_POST["pass"]) == "") {
          $errores[] = "No pusiste contrase&ntilde;a";
      }
      return $errores;
  }
```

Este mi `index.php`

```
if ($auth->estaLogueado()){
  header("location:Principal/principal.php");exit;
}else{
  if(isset($_POST['modal-type']) == 'register'){
    $errores = Validar::validarUsuario($_POST);
    if(empty($errores)){
    $usuario = new Usuario($_POST);
    $usuario->setPassword($_POST["pass"]);
    $repositorio->getUserRepository()->guardarUsuario($usuario);
    }
  }
  if(isset($_POST['modal-type']) == 'login'){
        $errores = $validar->validarLogin();
      if(empty($errores)){
      $usuario = $repositorio->getUserRepository()->getUsuarioByMail($_POST["mail"]);
      $auth->loguear($usuario);
      if (isset($_POST["recuerdame"])){
        setcookie("usuarioLogueado", $usuario->getId(), time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 3);
      }
      header("location:Principal/principal.php");
      exit;
    }
  }
}
```

form login

```
<div class="modal fade" id="user_login" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h2 class="modal-title" style="display:block" id="user_login">Iniciar Sesion</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                                  <!-- MODAL BODY LOGIN -->
                <div id="user_login" style='display:block'>
                  <form action="index.php" method="POST">
                          <?php if(!empty($errores)) {?>
                          <div id="errores">
                            <ul id="errorno">
                                <?php foreach ($errores as $error){?>
                                  <li>
                                  <?php echo $error;?>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <?php  }}?>
                        </div>

                        <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook">
                        Iniciar sesion con Facebook
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook" id='redessociales' aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                        <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google">
                        Iniciar sesion con Google
                        <i class="fa fa-google" id='redessociales' aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>

                        <input type="hidden" name="modal-type" value="login" />
                        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autofocus="" >


                        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Contraseña</label>
                        <input type="password" id="pass" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">

                      <div class="Checkbox">
                        <label>
                          <input type="checkbox" value="recuerdame">Recuerdame
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="submit" value='login' name="submit" type="submit">Iniciar Sesion</button>
                      </div>
                      <a href="#user_recovery" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal">Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
                    </form>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user_register">Registrate!</button>
                      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    </div>
                                        </div>
                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
```

form register

```
<div id="user_register" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="z-index: 1600;">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <!-- Modal content-->
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                          <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                            <h2 class="modal-title" style="display:block">Registrarse</h2>
                                          </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                              <div id="user_register" style='display:block'>
                                                <form action="index.php" method="POST">
                                                        <?php if(!empty($errores)) {?>
                                                        <div id="errores">
                                                          <ul>
                                                              <?php foreach ($errores as $error){?>
                                                                <li>
                                                                <?php echo $error;?>
                                                              </li>
                                                          </ul>
                                                          <?php  }}?>
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div>

                                                                                <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook">
                                                    Registrate con Facebook
                                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook" id='redessociales' aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                                                    <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google">
                                                    Registrate con Google
                                                    <i class="fa fa-google" id='redessociales' aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                    </a>


                                      <input type="hidden" name="modal-type" value="register" />

                                                      <label for="nombre" class='sr-only'>Nombre:</label>
                                                      <input  id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" class='form-control' placeholder="Nombre">

                                                                                <label for="nombre" class='sr-only'>Apellido:</label>
                                                      <input  id="apellido" type="text" name="apellido" class='form-control' placeholder="Apellido">

                                                                                <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autofocus="">

                                                    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Contraseña</label>
                                                    <input type="password" id="pass" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">

                                                      <label for="confirmarContrasena" class='sr-only'>Repita contraseña:</label>
                                                      <input type="password" name="cpass" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirma Contraseña">

                                                      <label for="sexo">Sexo:</label>
                                                      <select name="sexo" class='form-control' id="sexo">
                                                          <option value="M">Masculino</option>
                                                          <option value="F">Femenino</option>
                                                      </select>

                                                      <label for="nacimiento">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
                                                      <input type="date" name="nacimiento"  id="nacimiento" class='form-control'placeholder="aaaa-mm-dd">
                                                      <li>
                                                          <button type="submit" value='register' id='botonregistrarse'class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Registrate!</button>
                                                      </li>
                                                      </div>
                                                  </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user_login">Iniciar Sesion</button>
                                      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                    </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Hola. Según aparece en los avisos de php el problema se produce en el archivo usuario.php.  Notice: Undefined index: nombre in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DHproyect/clases/usuario.php on line 16

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en `validar.php` ya que estás usando la misma comprobación para el formulario de login y el de registro, por lo que cuando un usuario intenta logearse, `validarUsuario` espera el resto de los parametros.

La solución sería usar [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-key-exists.php), con esta función compruebas si el array con tiene la llave a verificar, y luego de verificar si existe recién hace la comprobación de si está vacía o no.

```
public static function validarUsuario($miUsuario){
  $errores = [];

  if(trim($miUsuario["mail"])== ""){
    $errores[] = "Falta el mail";
  }

  if(!filter_var($miUsuario["mail"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
      $errores[] = "Formato email incorrecto";
    }

  if(trim($miUsuario["pass"]) == ""){
    $errores[]= "Falta el password";
  }

  if($miUsuario['modal-type'] == "register"){
    if(trim($miUsuario["nombre"]) == ""){
      $errores[] = "Falta el nombre";
    }

    if(trim($miUsuario["apellido"]) == ''){
      $errores[] = "Falta el apellido";
    }

    if(trim($miUsuario["cpass"]) == ""){
      $errores[] = "Confirma el password";
    }

    if(!isset($miUsuario["sexo"])){
      $errores[] = "Selecciona un sexo";
    }

    if(!date($miUsuario["nacimiento"])){
      $errores[] = "Escribi bien la fecha";
    }

    if($miUsuario["pass"] != $miUsuario["cpass"]){
      $errores[] = "Las contraseñas no coinciden";
    }
  }

  return $errores;
}

function validarLogin(){
    $errores = [];
    if (trim($_POST["mail"]) == "") {
        $errores[] = "No pusiste email";
    } else if (!$this->userRepository->existeElMail($_POST["mail"])) {
        $errores[] = "El mail no existe";
    } else if (!$this->userRepository->usuarioValido($_POST["mail"], $_POST["pass"])) {
        $errores [] = "El usuario no es valido";
    }
    if (trim($_POST["pass"]) == "") {
        $errores[] = "No pusiste contrase&ntilde;a";
    }
    return $errores;
}
```

Comment: Hola y gracias por ayudarme! No funciono! sigue tirando lo mismo! Gracias igual!

Comment: Aquí he simplificado el código para probarlo para que veas que funciona http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b69e4f28ede3d2241fa6215da0708bd9394d1c66

¿a ti te siguen apareciendo los mismos errores?

Comment: he editado el código, esta vez si o si no deberían aparecer los errores

Comment: Si me sigue tirando errores! que sera y cada vez mas! Osea con el codigo que me pasaste es como si hiciera ahora todavia mas validaciones!

Comment: Seguramente es porque estoy trabajando con modales

Comment: Ahi resubi con los modales correspondientes! gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: he vuelto a modificar el código, esta vez el planteamiento es más simple y creo que debería funcionar

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46844/discussion-between-hernan-bessera-and-gepd).

Answer (score 0):

Hola buen dia puedes intentar con lo siguiente  :
inicializar los índices para saber si existen en el array y si no los generas en blanco y ya entran a tus validaciones sin tronar

```
public static function validarUsuario($miUsuario){
    $errores = [];
    $miUsuario["nombre"]=isset($miUsuario["nombre"])?$miUsuario["nombre"]:""; // inicializar los índices para saber si existen en el array y si no los generas en blanco y ya entran a tus validaciones sin que marque error.

    if(trim($miUsuario["nombre"]) == ""){
      $errores[] = "Falta el nombre";
    }

    return $errores;
  }
```

espero te sea de ayuda.

saludos.